# Show and hide button in ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a button in every item of my ng-repeat list. The button is hidden by default, I want to show the button when the user selects the list item and hide the button when the user selects another list item. I am not able to get this to work, the button stays hidden when the user selects the list item.

Here are the relevant bit of code from what I have tried so far.

The HTML:

```html
<ul ng-repeat="thing in things" role="presentation" id="thing-details" ng-click="selectthing($index)" >
   <li>
        <p>Name: {{thing.name}} </p>

        <button class="btn btn-block" ng-show="false" id="thing-delete" >Delete</button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The JS code:

```js
$scope.selectthing = function(idx) {

      $(this).find('ul.btn').show();  // this is not working

      .
      .
      .
      // do some awesome stuff with the selected thing.
}
```

My question is: How do I get the button to show when the user selects the list item and hide the button when the user another list item ?

Comment: I believe you are having issues because you are mixing ng-show and the show/hidden attribute.  ng-show will always be false thus always hiding the element.

Comment: Ok, do you have any suggestion on how I can implement this functionality ?

Comment: My recommendation would be to get rid of the ng-show set it to style='display:none' then use .show() and .hide().

Comment: As stated in the answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29898826/4252741), ng-show should reference something on the controller model. Then the ng-click should change the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it:

```
<ul ng-repeat="thing in things">
  <li>
    <p ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex = $index">Name: {{thing.name}}</p>

    <button class="btn btn-block" 
            ng-show="$parent.selectedIndex == $index">Delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zrWo2Dfw86DAhR6sos62?p=preview)

Comment: nice and concise.  Ah!  Yes, $parent is critical, otherwise it will set selectedIndex on the individual repeat scope.  (Unless you use a scope method instead of doing it direct from the view).

Comment: How can I hide the delete button when I call onclick function to it.

Comment: @User123 following code snippet from answer you can define property eg `_deleted` on `thing` and set it to `true` in `on-click` function.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Angular and jQuery, and that's the slippery slope to Hell :)  (ok, caveat: directives, but that's a different story).  If you find yourself about to write jQuery in your controller then alarm bells should ring that you are breaking the MVC separation and missing something simpler.

The trick here is to make your ng-show conditional on whether the current item being rendered is the selected one.  To detect that, make a note in your scope of the selected index.  Like so ...

HTML view:

```
<ul ng-repeat="thing in things" role="presentation" id="thing-details" ng-click="selectthing($index)" >
    <li>
        <p>Name: {{thing.name}} </p>

        <button class="btn btn-block" ng-show="$index===selectedIndex" id="thing-delete" >Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS controller:

```
$scope.selectedIndex = -1;
$scope.selectthing = function(idx) {

    $scope.selectedIndex = idx;

    .
    .
    .
    // do some awesome stuff with the selected thing.
}
```

Comment: @doe strictly speaking, you're right, it wasn't being initialized (I've edited to init to -1 to be clear) but it worked anyway because it would never match a row where `$index===undefined`. Is that what you meant?